# Tracing path between points A and B that lie on a simple shape using Paper.js

Tags: geometry, paperjs

In a paper.js project, I have two points A and B, that lie on a simple shape. This shape can be a circle, a line, an ellipse, a rectangle, etc. I need to highlight the points that lie on the shape from point A to point B.

For example, if I was given the triangle below, and the points A and B, I want to high the line AB as shown in the diagram.

[image of a triangle drawn in black with line AB highlighted in purple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/998nj.png)

I would like to understand how to implement this. Of course I can do it the brute force way by tracing tangent points, but that will be slow. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: This could be.a very interesting question if you made it more specific, with some code setup. Otherwise, only a generic answer can be given, that is hardly helpful, like use `path.getOffsetOf(point)` get the offsets for the two points and then use `path.getPointAtOfset` ... however, you probably don't want a collection of points but rather a new curve that overlaps the original one between the two points, which is much more complicated and interesting.

Comment: As kikon, I am not sure to understand your problem, a sketch would help. But [the `getPointAt()` example](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getpointat-offset) seems to be what you want, right?

Comment: I provided a simple example, in this case I can just draw a purple line and that will cover all the points between A and B which lie on the triangle.

Comment: Can't you just draw a highlighted line over the shape?

Comment: I can draw a line for the very simple example I gave. But for more complex examples with curves I can't draw a line. I gave the example just for demonstration.